# Minimum formation sequence length for a logic formula equals number of of subformulas

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $SF(\varphi)$ be the group of **subformulas** of formula $\varphi$, defined as follows:
>
> - If $\varphi=p$ is atomic variable, $SF(\varphi)=\{p\}$
> - If $\varphi=\neg\alpha$ then, $SF(\varphi)=\{\neg\alpha\} \cup SF(\alpha)$
> - If $\varphi=\alpha \circ \beta$, then $SF(\varphi)=\{\alpha \circ \beta\} \cup SF(\alpha)\cup SF(\beta)$

Theorem:

> Let $\varphi$ be a formula, then $|SF(\varphi)|$ = minimum *formation sequence* length for $\varphi$.

*(a formation sequence is defined in this post for example: [Formation sequence for a logic formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179573/formation-sequence-for-a-logic-formula))*

I tried to prove it using structural induction on a formula $\varphi$, but I failed to show the induction step for binary connective. I managed only to achieve the following bound: 
$|SF(\varphi)|=|\{\alpha \circ \beta\} \cup SF(\alpha)\cup SF(\beta)|\leq1+| SF(\alpha)| +  |SF(\beta)|$.

Please advise.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed some trickiness in the case of a binary connective.  The issue is that $SF(\alpha)$ and $SF(\beta)$ might contain some elements in common, and so the obvious formation sequence of length $1+|SF(\alpha)|+|SF(\beta)|$ you can get by concatenating formation sequences for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ might actually be longer than $|SF(\varphi)|$.  The idea to fix this is that any common subformula of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ will appear both in the formation sequence for $\alpha$ and the formation sequence for $\beta$, and so when you concatenate the formation sequences you can delete the duplicate entries (since they are redundant) and end up with a sequence of length just $|SF(\varphi)|$.

There are various ways you can make this idea formal.  For instance, you could first prove that any formation sequence for $\varphi$ must contain all subformulas of $\varphi$.  Then, you can prove by induction on $\varphi$ that there exists a formation sequence for $\varphi$ in which every term of the sequence is a subformula of $\varphi$.  Then, you can take such a sequence and remove each term which is a duplicate of a previous term, and this will give you a formation sequence of length $|SF(\varphi)|$ since every subformula will appear exactly once.

Comment: Can you please finish your answer? You are really helping me here.

Comment: Oops, the answer was finished; that last paragraph was from an earlier draft that I meant to remove.

Comment: How would you prove that that any formation sequence for $\varphi$ must contain all subformulas of $\varphi$? By contradiction or using structural induction? (or anything else?)

Comment: Pretty much the only way you can ever prove something like this is by structural induction, since that's the only way you can possibly use the definition.

Comment: Thank you very much!