# Proving that an effective procedure is correct

Tags: algorithms, logic, recursive-algorithms

I will start with definitions, theorems, and a few solved exercises which I am taking as theorems now. My actual question will be last, if you want to scroll ahead to see it.

**Definitions:**

> **(1)** The *set of wffs* is the intersection of all sets $\mathscr{S}$ of formulas such that:
>
> (i) $\mathbf{p} \in \mathscr{S}$ for each propositional variable $\mathbf{p}$.
>
> (ii) For each formula $\mathbf{A}$ if $\mathbf{A} \in \mathscr{S}$, then $\mathord{\sim} \mathbf{A} \in \mathscr{S}$.
>
> (iii) For all formulas $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$, if $\mathbf{A} \in \mathscr{S}$ and $\mathbf{B} \in \mathscr{S}$, then $\left[\mathbf{A} \lor \mathbf{B} \right] \in \mathscr{S}$.
>
> **(2)** A *wff* is a member of the set of wffs.

**Theorems:**

> **1000 Principle of Induction on the Construction of a Wff.** Let $\mathscr{R}$ be a property of formulas, and let $\mathscr{R}(\mathbf{A})$ mean that $\mathbf{A}$ has property $\mathscr{R}$. Suppose
>
> (1) $\mathscr{R}(\mathbf{q})$ for each propositional variable $\mathbf{q}$.
>
> (2) Whenever $\mathscr{R}(\mathbf{A})$, then $\mathscr{R}(\mathord{\sim} \mathbf{A})$.
>
> (3) Whenever $\mathscr{R}(\mathbf{A})$ and $\mathscr{R}(\mathbf{B})$, then $\mathscr{R}([\mathbf{A} \lor \mathbf{B}])$.
>
> Then every wff has property $\mathscr{R}$.

**Completed Exercises which can be used as Theorems:**

> **X1000.** Using the definition of the set of wffs, show that if $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are wffs, then $\mathord{\sim} \mathbf{A}$ and $\left[\mathbf{A} \lor \mathbf{B}\right]$ are also wffs.
>
> **X1001.** A *formation sequence for a formula $\mathbf{Y}$* is a finite sequence $\mathbf{Y}_1, ..., \mathbf{Y}_m$ of formulas such that $\mathbf{Y}_m$ is $\mathbf{Y}$ and for each $i$ ($1 \le i \le m$), one of the following conditions holds:
>
> (a) $\mathbf{Y}_i$ is a propositional variable;
>
> (b) there is $j < i$ such that $\mathbf{Y}_i$ is $\mathord{\sim} \mathbf{Y}_j$;
>
> (c) there are indices $j < i$ and $k < i$ such that $\mathbf{Y}_i$ is $\left[ \mathbf{Y}_j \lor \mathbf{Y}_k \right]$.
>
> Prove that a formula $\mathbf{Y}$ is well-formed iff it has a formation sequence. (*Hint*: [Metatheorem 1000](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178932/induction-without-integers-aka-structural-induction/178933#178933) may be useful.)
>
> **X1002.** Prove that every wff is of the form $\mathbf{p}$ for some propositional variable $\mathbf{p}$, or of the form $\mathord{\sim} \mathbf{A}$ or $\left[\mathbf{A} \lor \mathbf{B}\right]$ for some wffs $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$.

**Current Exercise:**

Using the results above, describe an effective procedure which can be used to determine of an arbitrary formula $\mathbf{Y}$ whether or not it is a wf, and prove that this procedure is correct.

**My Effective Procedure:**

Suppose $\mathbf{X}$ is a formula. If $\mathbf{X}$ is a propositional variable, then $\mathbf{X}$ is wf. If $\mathbf{X}$ is $\mathord{\sim} \mathbf{Y}$ for some formula $\mathbf{Y}$, then $\mathbf{X}$ is wf iff $\mathbf{Y}$ is wf. If $\mathbf{X}$ is $\left[ \mathbf{Y} \right]$ for some formula $\mathbf{Y}$, then proceed as follows:

- If $\mathbf{Y}$ contains no occurence of $\lor$, then $\mathbf{Y}$ is *not* wf.
- Otherwise, for the $i$th occurrence of $\lor$ in $\mathbf{Y}$, let $\mathbf{Y}$ be $\mathbf{A}_i \lor \mathbf{B}_i$. $\mathbf{X}$ is wf iff $\mathbf{A}_i$ and $\mathbf{B}_i$ are both wf for some integer $i$ with $1 \le i \le n$ where $\mathbf{Y}$ contains $n$ occurrences of $\lor$.

If none of the previous conditions applies, then $\mathbf{X}$ is not wf.

**Proof that Effective Procedure is Correct:**

We proceed by *proof by duh!*

**Serious attempt at a proof:**

Suppose $\mathbf{X}$is a wff. By X1002, $\mathbf{X}$ is of the form $\mathbf{p}$ for some propositional variable $\mathbf{p}$, or of the form $\mathord{\sim} \mathbf{A}$ or $\left[\mathbf{A} \lor \mathbf{B}\right]$ for some wffs $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$. If $\mathbf{X}$ is of the form $\mathbf{p}$ for some propositional variable $\mathbf{p}$ then the algorithm correctly reports that $\mathbf{X}$ is wf. If $\mathbf{X}$ is of the form $\mathord{\sim} \mathbf{A}$ for some wff $\mathbf{A}$, the the algorithm also clearly gives the correct result.

**Edited Question:**

Now I'm stuck on the third case. I need to show that if $\mathbf{X}$ is of the form $\left[\mathbf{A} \lor \mathbf{B}\right]$ for some wffs $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ then the algorithm correctly reports that $\mathbf{X}$ is wf. I'm uncertain that simply stating that this is obvious is sufficient.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: "*duh*" is induction.

Comment: If you want to show something is effective, you could develop a coding for the variables and logical symbols and then write a Turing Machine that carries out your algorithm. Again to prove that the algorithm works, you would still need induction.

Comment: @William I'm more of a programmer than a mathematician. I could probably code a wff parser in one of several languages in a few minutes. I'm a little OCD as well, so I agonize (perhaps a little too much) over the details in my math studies (and in my programming).

Comment: @Code-Guru That is fine. Most programming languages can simulate arbitrary Turing Machines and Turing Machine can simulate most programming languages. But most of the time, no one ever writes a Turing machine to prove something is effective. They usually use the Church-Turing Thesis and essentially conclude that if you think you can carry this out by hand, then it is probably effective.

Comment: @Code-Guru: Although your algorithm is correct, if you put on your programmer hat for a moment you'll see that it's likely to be very inefficient (exponential time) because it tries every occurrence of $\lor$ as a break point.  The right break point can be found more efficiently by counting brackets.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks for the comment. Efficiency isn't my primary concern here. I could (relatively) easily write a LALR parser, but that might be overkill. If/when I want to actually implement such an algorithm, I will certainly revisit the trade-off between run-time efficiency and amount of time to write and debug the code.